# Java Regex for positive numeric and few special symbol validation for a particular pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a **String ex=1,2,3,4,5-7,8,9,10-15,34,898**

In the above string my regex has to validate the following things

1. ex String should contain only numeric values(0-9) and two special characters 
   ,- alone.
2. Regex should validate ex should not start with space,cama(,) and 
   hyfun(-),same should not end.
3. After cama(,) should have numeric value alone.
4. String ex should support only positive numbers 0-9.
5. After hyfun(-) there should be a positive numeric value alone.
6. It should not allow space any where in the string.
7. hyfun(-) symbol is the range indicator in the above ex String, so it should 
   prefix and suffix with a positive numeric value.
8. cama(,) is a separator for each element in the string, so it should succeeded  with positive numeric value.

so for i have tried with individual regex which making my code clumsy and few cases its failing

```
 //Regex Pattern for validating number alone as its starting and ending of the string
        Pattern digits = Pattern.compile ("^[0-9](.*[0-9])?$");
 //Regex Pattern for validating special character along with the digits alone
        Pattern special = Pattern.compile("^[0-9,-]*$");
//Regex Pattern for validating only positive numeric values alone
        Pattern positiveNumeric = Pattern.compile("^\\d+$");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general regex pattern which should work:

```
^\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$
```

### Demo

The quantity `\d+(?:-\d+)?` says to match one or more digits, followed optionally by a hyphen and then one or more other digits.  Then, we append this to end of the pattern:

```
(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*
```

This matches a comma followed by another digit/range of digits group, zero or more times.

Note that the `^` and `$` anchors may not be necessary in your Java code if you are using, e.g. `String#matches`, which automatically adds these anchors.